# Designing a simple system to track the number of times links have been clicked

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been having a think about how to track and count the number of clicks within my Meteor application.

I have a list of links to externals sites and I want to count how many times they have been clicked.  The link should open within a modal / iframe so the user isn't redirected away to the external site.  I would create an option on the modal for the page to be opened in a new window/tab.

The only solution I have come up with so far is using a link containing a hashid hashid=sdfkljn24krj23n, checking the hashid against the db and the return the corresponding URL from the db which would then be opened within the modal/iframe.

For creating the hashids I was thinking of using [hashids.node.js](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.node.js)

I can see doing it this way could get complex on the db as I would need to store the userid, the number of clicks per website, the hashids.  I'm likely to have many hash ids to one url so I can track clicks for multiple users.

I just want to create a basic report that has simple data:

```
user | number of clicks 
a    |        1
b    |        5
c    |        3


Total number of users | Total number of clicks
        3             |           9
```

Does this approach sound ok?

Comment: Would Google Analytics (http://www.google.com/analytics/) give you the data you need?

Comment: It might well do but I want to show the user in realtime how many links they have visited.  So as soon as the external site has loaded increase the number by one.

Comment: It looks like you can add an onclick action to your outgoing links and make an ajax call to your app to track the clicks. (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en)

Comment: Cheers for that ..... I'll need to have a good read at it.  Just want a simple solution for the moment.

Comment: I would suggest using a combination of the 'target' attribute and an 'onclick' event because "<a href="http://notgoogle.com?hashid=dlsfjdks">Google</a>" seems like phishing.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea :)

Comment: well all the cool kids do it. If you click on the first result when you search Google for "paypal", you get `https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com%2F&ei=sjMSVK_ALM2eugTV64KABg&usg=AFQjCNGLTC3kLD7W4xWhezR7XoOYkhoGQQ&sig2=_Mu8TzWQk8FGM54bj0eNFQ&bvm=bv.75097201,d.dGc`

Comment: That's an advertisement link. The actual first search result goes to https://www.paypal.com

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using jQuery:

```
$('a').onclick(function (event) {

  // Get the current user, however you’re currently tracking that:
  var user = App.getUser();

  // Get the URL of the link that was clicked, by parsing your HashId:
  var url = App.parseHashId(event.target.href);

  // Update the UI with the new click counts:
  App.updateClickCounts( user, url );

  // Save this information to the server:
  $.post(App.getServerURL(), { user: user, url: url }, function ( data ) {
    // Optional: do something on success
  };
});
```

And depending on your app, write `getUser`, `parseHashId`, `getServerURL` and `updateClickCounts` functions as appropriate.